# Merging repeated items in list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python. And now i am trying  to merge these dictionaries based on a specific key entity in python. Example the list of dictionary is:

```
[[{'max_score': u'110', 'total_mark': u'75', 'student': <student_details: Komal>}, {'max_score': u'110', 'total_mark': u'75', 'student': <student_details: Java>}],
 [{'max_score': u'131', 'total_mark': u'99', 'student': <student_details: Komal>}, {'max_score': u'131', 'total_mark': u'64', 'student': <student_details: Java>}],
 [{'max_score': u'138', 'total_mark': u'110', 'student': <student_details: Komal>}, {'max_score': u'138', 'total_mark': u'80', 'student': <student_details: Java>}]]
```

and i am trying to convert this record in their single individual records like:

```
    ['student': <student_details: Komal>:[
{'max_score': u'110', 'total_mark': u'75', }
{'max_score': u'131', 'total_mark': u'99'},
{'max_score': u'138', 'total_mark': u'110'}],
'student': <student_details: Java>:[
{'max_score': u'110', 'total_mark': u'75'}, 
{'max_score': u'131', 'total_mark': u'64'}, 
{'max_score': u'138', 'total_mark': u'80'}]]
```

please suggest me how can i achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the structure of your output. Is it list or dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the closest you could come to your expected output is:

```
studs = [
 [{'max_score': u'110', 'total_mark': u'75', 'student': '<student_details: Komal>'}, 
  {'max_score': u'110', 'total_mark': u'75', 'student': '<student_details: Java>'}], 
 [{'max_score': u'131', 'total_mark': u'99', 'student': '<student_details: Komal>'}, 
  {'max_score': u'131', 'total_mark': u'64', 'student': '<student_details: Java>'}], 
 [{'max_score': u'138', 'total_mark': u'110', 'student': '<student_details: Komal>'}, 
  {'max_score': u'138', 'total_mark': u'80', 'student': '<student_details: Java>'}]]


d={}
for studlist in studs:
    for stud in studlist:
        # use the 'student' - entry as tuple as key and append a set of each scores data
        d.setdefault( ('student',stud['student']) , []).append(
            { 'max_score' : stud['max_score'], 'total_mark': stud['total_mark'] })

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{('student', '<student_details: Komal>'): 
    [{'max_score': '110', 'total_mark': '75'}, 
     {'max_score': '131', 'total_mark': '99'}, 
     {'max_score': '138', 'total_mark': '110'}], 
('student', '<student_details: Java>'): 
    [{'max_score': '110', 'total_mark': '75'}, 
     {'max_score': '131', 'total_mark': '64'}, 
     {'max_score': '138', 'total_mark': '80'}]
}
```

Which is a set with `tuples` as `key`, the tuples are `('student', 'your details')` and values of `list` of `dict` of your scores. You need a hashable type as key into a dict - tuples are immutable and thus hashable and valid as key.

Comment: this is a good example which can be easily translated to use `collections.defaultdict`. But it does what OP asks and is a good solution. +1

Comment: @jp_data_analysis OP is asking for nonsense. Praising an answer with guesswork might be a tad too much.

Comment: It does the closest thing possible to what he asked IMO. The conversion of some object type to string is contentious, but can be cleared up. Not too much at all.

Comment: thanks for the help. But how can i iterate the data in loop the normal iteration is not working over it.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis it's not about strings, it's about a nonsense output data structure. The question is unclear and has to be closed as such until OP clarifies.

Comment: @AndrasDeak. feel free to close it, then. It seems obvious to me and Patrick what the intention is (looking at the data..), even if OP has done a poor job of explaining the problem.

Comment: And maybe I should not have answered a not 100% clear formulated question...

Comment: @Patrick I'm afraid so. I know you mean well, but when (if...) OP clarifies it might invalidate your answer altogether (see also OP's vague comment about iteration).

Comment: @AndrasDeak Cant delete accepted answer?

Comment: You can't and anyway I don't think you should; it's a good answer. It's more of a suggestion going forward :)