# merging dictionary based on their similar specific values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I am trying to merge dictionary based on their similar specific values. Currently i have this dictionary:

```
    [{'max_score': '110', 'total_mark': '75', 'id': 1},
     {'max_score': '110', 'total_mark': '75', 'id': 2},
     {'max_score': '131', 'total_mark': '99', 'id': 1}, 
     {'max_score': '131', 'total_mark': '64', 'id': 2}]
```

and i am trying to merge them like:

```
    ['id': '1',
     'rec':[
             {'max_score': '110', 'total_mark': '75'},
             {'max_score': '131', 'total_mark': '99'}
           ],

     'id': '2',
     'rec':[
            {'max_score': '110', 'total_mark': '75'}, 
            {'max_score': '131', 'total_mark': '64'}
           ]
    ]
```

any help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple dicts with same key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946236/how-to-merge-multiple-dicts-with-same-key)

Comment: Define "similar."

Comment: @javed your expected o/p is wrong, Because list cannot have `id:1` like values.Also if you make it `dict` the problem is `id` and `rec` are duplicate keys.

Comment: i have updated my o/p sorry for the incorrect one. 
and "similar" mean here i want to merge the dict based on similar "id" so thats what similar defines here.

Comment: @javed still your desired o/p is wrong one . May be you can try the format of o/p that in those two answers given below.

Comment: Do you mean "identical", perhaps? "Similar" is not the same as "identical."

Comment: @DYZ actually he meant `same id`

Comment: Why did you not refine your "ON HOLD" question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719814/merging-repeated-items-in-list-of-dictionary-in-python - instead you are asking something almost similar again? - just wondering b/c you accepet my answer on that one. I find (ab)using SO as iterative "CodeRefiner" distasteful.

Comment: @VikasDamodar That's not what the OP said.

Comment: @DYZ In his expected o/p he group the dicts having the same id,.

Comment: @VikasDamodar We should not be _guessing_ what the OP means.

Comment: @DYZ I'am not guessing , OP clearly said in his comment `similar id`, just see 4th comment.

Comment: @VikasDamodar "Similar" means "resembling without being identical," not "same." That's exactly the problem.

Comment: @DYZ that's may be because of he is not deep in English.

Comment: i apologies for my English and this messy output all i wanted to merge the  records based no their ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a simple forloop

```
x = [{'max_score': '110', 'total_mark': '75', 'id': 1},
     {'max_score': '110', 'total_mark': '75', 'id': 2},
     {'max_score': '131', 'total_mark': '99', 'id': 1}, 
     {'max_score': '131', 'total_mark': '64', 'id': 2}]

d = {}
for i in x:
    if i["id"] not in d:
        d[i["id"]] = {'rec': [{'max_score': i['max_score'], 'total_mark': i['total_mark']}]}
    else:
        d[i["id"]]['rec'].append({'max_score': i['max_score'], 'total_mark': i['total_mark']})

print d
```

**Output**:

```
{1: {'rec': [{'total_mark': '75', 'max_score': '110'}, {'total_mark': '99', 'max_score': '131'}]}, 2: {'rec': [{'total_mark': '75', 'max_score': '110'}, {'total_mark': '64', 'max_score': '131'}]}}
```

Comment: `for i in x: d.setdefault(i["id"],[]).append({'max_score': i['max_score'], 'total_mark': i['total_mark']})` to get rid of `if: ... else: ...`

Comment: can you please help me to iterate this record?
the output is what i am expecting but i am not getting any way to retrieve the data. Help me to get the 'rec' of keys

Comment: @javed; again you can use a loop to get the "rec" list. example   for i in d: print d[i]["rec"]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am very new to python. I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    dict_data = {}
    for  val in data:
        score, mark, id_ = val
        if val[id_] in dict_data:
            dict_data[val[id_]]['rec'].append({"max_score":val[score],"total_mark":val[mark]})
        else:
            dict_data.setdefault(val[id_],{'rec':[{"max_score":val[score],"total_mark":val[mark]}]})
>>>{1: {'rec': [{'max_score': '75', 'total_mark': '110'},
                {'max_score': '99', 'total_mark': '131'}]},
   2: {'rec': [{'max_score': '75', 'total_mark': '110'},
               {'max_score': '64', 'total_mark': '131'}]}}
```